# ANYLOGIC How to read an event condition?

Tags: java, anylogic

I need to run the event in the pic with this condition (container == 0). Anyway, when the value of the variable becomes 0, the event is not triggered. How can I fix it? Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: (sorry, don't know this studio, but it looks very "Eclipse-like") Tried without semicolon?? So: "container==0"

Comment: @xerx593 I've tried... but problem remains unluckly

Comment: You are sure that `container` is updated correctly? What is the type of that variable?

Comment: @YasharAhmadov it’s an Int variable

Answer (score 2):

Conditional events are notoriously unfriendly to use for two reasons

1. They make your model slower - as the condition needs to be checked almost continuously
2. This almost continuously checking can lead to checks missing when the condition actually changed

Best practices is not too poll a variable and figure out when it changes but to control the changing of the variable and to the check there

So I suggest the following

1. Make the variable private
2. Create a setter and getter for the variable
3. In the setter check if the variable meets your condition `==0` and then call the code that is currently in the event.

Alternatively you can also call `onChange()` to force Anylogic to reevaluate all conditional events and transitions.

Comment: thank you so much for the support. I have two questions: 1- what are setter and getter? 2- how can I use onChange()? Do I need to insert in the same event containing the action or what? Thank you.

Comment: 1) Setters and getters - please google "java setters and getters"
2) You need to call the onChange() code for the agent that your event is on everytime something changes and you want AnyLogic to reevaluate the status of conditional events and transitions.